# Proving that $f + g, f \cdot g$, and $f/g$ are continuous using neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, continuity, real-numbers

This is Exercise 1 from Section 1.2, page 9, of *Topology and Groupoids* by Brown. I paraphrase portions of the book to hopefully improve clarity.

I found questions such as [Continuity of the sum of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744896/continuity-of-the-sum-of-continuous-functions) and [Topology: Continuous Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317661/topology-continuous-functions) but they look a bit too advanced and don't quite address my problems.

**Exercise:**

Let $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g \colon B \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$, then $f + g$ (on domain $A \cap B$), $f \cdot g$ (on domain $A \cap B$), and $\frac{f}{g}$ (on domain $(A \cap B) \setminus \{x \in B \colon g(x) = 0 \}$) are all continuous at $a$ (assuming $a$ lies within the respective domains).

I am supposed to use the following results in my proofs (from Exercises 6 and 7 on page 4 of the same book):

> Let $C$ be a neighborhood of $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $a + b = c$. Then there are neighborhoods $A$ of $a$ and $B$ of $b$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ imply $x + y \in C$.
>
> If $c = ab$ then there are neighborhoods $A^{\prime}$ of $a$ and $B^{\prime}$ of $b$ such that $x \in A^{\prime}$ and $y \in B^{\prime}$ imply $xy \in C$.

**Other information:**

The definition of continuity I have decided to use is Definition $C^{\prime}$ from page 4 of the same book. It says that the function $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a \in A$ if for each neighborhood $N$ of $f(a)$, there is a neighborhood $M$ of $a$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \in M \cap A \Rightarrow f(x) \in N.$

**Attempt for $f + g$:**

Consider some neighborhood $N$ of $(f + g)(a)$. We want to show that there is a neighborhood $M$ of $a$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \in M \cap A \cap B \Rightarrow (f + g)(x) \in N$.

Using the additive result mentioned, we know that given $N$ there are neighborhoods $N^{\prime}$ of $f(a)$ and $N^{\prime \prime}$ of $g(a)$ such that $y \in N^{\prime}$ and $z \in N^{\prime \prime}$ imply $y + z \in N$.

By continuity of $f$ at $a$, we know that given $N^{\prime}$, there is a neighborhood $M^{\prime}$ of $a$ such that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \in M^{\prime} \cap A \cap B \Rightarrow f(\alpha) \in N^{\prime}$.

By continuity of $g$ at $a$, we know that given $N^{\prime \prime}$, there is a neighborhood $M ^{\prime \prime}$ of $a$ such that for all $\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \beta \in M^{\prime \prime} \cap A \cap B \Rightarrow g(\beta) \in N^{\prime \prime}$.

If we let $M = M^{\prime} \cap M^{\prime \prime}$, then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \in M \cap A \cap B$ implies $f(x) \in N^{\prime}$ and $g(x) \in N^{\prime}$, which implies that $f(x) + g(x) = (f + g)(x) \in N$ as desired.

**Attempt for $f \cdot g$:**

This proof proceeds the same way as the prior one, except that we replace all instances of $+$ with $\cdot$ and rely on the multiplicative result mentioned.

**Questions:**

Are my two proofs above correct?

How should I prove continuity of $\frac{f}{g}$? I do not understand how to use the multiplicative result mentioned to help me here. Do I need to prove a similar result for $c = \frac{a}{b}$?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

After some thought, here is my attempt for $\frac{f}{g}$. I use Section 1.1 Exercise 8 from the text, which gives the result that if $C$ is a neighborhood of $c$, where $c \neq 0$, then there is a neighborhood $C^{\prime}$ of $\frac{1}{c}$ such that if $x$ is in $C^{\prime}$, then $\frac{1}{x}$ is in $C$. My attempt:

Looking at the multiplicative result, there is no reason we cannot consider the case when $c = a \cdot \frac{1}{b}$ since after all it's still just the product of two numbers.

Consider some neighborhood $N$ of $\big( \frac{f}{g} \big) (a)$. By the multiplicative result there must be neighborhoods $N^{\prime}$ of $f(a)$ and $N^{\prime \prime}$ of $\frac{1}{g(a)}$ such that $y \in N^{\prime}$ and $\frac{1}{z} \in N^{\prime \prime}$ imply $\frac{y}{z} \in N$.

By continuity of $f$ at $a$, given $N^{\prime}$ there is a neighborhood $M^{\prime}$ of $a$ such that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \in M^{\prime} \cap (A \cap B) \setminus \{x \in B \colon g(x) = 0 \} \Rightarrow f(\alpha) \in N^{\prime}$.

For $g$, we need to call on Exercise 8 mentioned above. We have a neighborhood $N^{\prime \prime}$ of $\frac{1}{g(a)}$. Exercise 8 tells us that there is a neighborhood $N^{\prime \prime \prime}$ of $g(a)$ such that if $z \in N^{\prime \prime \prime}, \frac{1}{z} \in N^{\prime \prime}$. By continuity of $g$ at $a$, given $N^{\prime \prime \prime}$ there is a neighborhood $M^{\prime \prime \prime}$ of $a$ such that for all $\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \beta \in M^{\prime \prime \prime} \cap (A \cap B) \setminus \{x \in B \colon g(x) = 0 \} \Rightarrow g(\beta) \in N^{\prime \prime \prime}$. Since $g(\beta) \in N^{\prime \prime \prime}$, we must have $\frac{1}{g(\beta)} \in N^{\prime \prime}$.

Let $M = M^{\prime} \cap M^{\prime \prime \prime}$. Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \in M \cap (A \cap B) \setminus \{x \in B \colon g(x) = 0 \}$ implies $f(x) \in N^{\prime}$ and $\frac{1}{g(x)} \in N^{\prime \prime}$, which implies that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \big( \frac{f}{g} \big) (x) \in N$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by what you posted in your definitions they're correct. Now if you know how to prove that for the product then for the quotient is the same thing. You only take $c=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{b}\cdot a$. That is, you see it like a product.

Comment: So once I assert that given neighborhood $C$ of $c = \frac{1}{b} \cdot a$, there are neighborhoods $A$ of $a$ and $B$ of $\frac{1}{b}$ such that $x \in A$ and $\frac{1}{y} \in B$ imply $\frac{x}{y} \in C$, then the rest of the proof is basically the same as in the case $f \cdot g$?

Comment: You know what, I think I'm supposed to use this additional result from the book: let $C$ be a neighborhood of $c$, where $c \neq 0$. Then there is a neighborhood $C^{\prime}$ of $\frac{1}{c}$ such that if $x \in C^{\prime}$, then $\frac{1}{x} \in C$.

Comment: I added an attempt to show $\frac{f}{g}$ is continuous to my question. If you come back to this post, can you please take a look at it? Thanks for your help either way.